# Is it possible to define auto layout constraints relative to unknown UIViews?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Let's say I have a UIView or UIViewController I want to use in many places throughout the app.

While I don't know how or where it'll ultimately be displayed, I know I always want it to have half the width of its parent, and be pinned to the right.

If I wanted to achieve something like this in HTML/CSS, I would apply the following style:

```
.floatRight{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

<div class="floatRight"> foobar </div>
```

I've tried using NSLayoutConstraints, but as far as I can tell I can only specify constraints relative to other views, which means I have to know where my view will be placed ahead of time.

Is there any way in iOS that I can specify "this view should be this tall and always be as far right as possible" without knowing the parent or surrounding views ahead of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While I don't know how or where it'll ultimately be displayed, I know I always want it to have half the width of its parent, and be pinned to the right.

You have to wait until the view has a parent, but that's not difficult. Use a custom UIView subclass. In that subclass, override `didMoveToSuperview`, and in your override, create and activate the constraints. As you do that, refer to the view's superview as `self.superview!`; that's all your code needs to know.

Comment: This will let me position relative to an unknown parent.

What if I also wanted to layout my view relative to unknown sibling views? For example if I want to add 3 subviews to a container view so that they end up in a horizontal row. I want each subview defined such that it'll try to be as far right as possible while respecting other subviews that were inserted first.

Comment: But that is not what you asked. The question was: Is there any way in iOS that I can specify "this view should be this tall and always be as far right as possible" without knowing the parent or surrounding views ahead of time? That is what I answered.

Comment: Yes and thank you for that. But I would also like to know this, which seems closely related